# Leaving fullscreen mode movie, it breaks navigation bar

Tags: fullscreen, navbar, appcelerator, movie, appcelerator-titanium

I don't find solution to this problem. 
I have tabgroup, on button click I open new window with movie. If I click fullscreen mode button, when I exit from this mode my navigation bar is broken (look attachment). 
I have checked all my code but I don't understand what is the problem.

I think that I have this problem from sdk 5.0.0, before it worked fine. 
On kitchen sink app works fine, but I'm not able to replicate it on my app.

```
function Video(_args) {

var self = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
    url: _args.url,
    backgroundColor:'#111',
    mediaControlStyle:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT, 
    scalingMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT
});

self.add(activeMovie);

activeMovie.play();

self.addEventListener('close', function() {
    LOG.info("Window closed");
    activeMovie.stop();
});

return self;
};

module.exports = Video;
```

Open movie window

```
var Video = require('common/Video');
var winVideo = Video({url: videourl});
self.containingTab.open(winVideo);
```

[before fullscreen mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIicp.jpg)
[after fullscreen mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJsKT.jpg)

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug. Check the jira ticket [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/TIMOB-20112)

Comment: It's a bug after 5.1.1. What sdk does the kitchen sink use?

Comment: The problem is in 5.1.1 too and kitchen sink works fine with 5.1.1 and 5.1.2 too.